# Как получить текущие состояние react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Вопрос такой: есть два компонента в первом компоненте есть состояние которое меняется  когда идет скрол страницы оно же передается через `props` к в второму компоненту.

Как второму компоненту постоянно получать уже измененное состояние из первого?

Первый компонент:

```
state = { classelemetn: true, buttonopacty:1, num:0 };

<Skil num = {this.state.num}/>

componentDidMount() {
    let d = document.getElementById("go_0skil_bar");
    let topPos = d.offsetTop;
    let flag2 = false;

    window.onscroll = () => {
        let scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        let rez = topPos - scrolled;

        if (rez < 700 && flag2 === false) {
            this.setState({ num:rez });
            flag2 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Второй компонент:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.num <= 700 && this.props.num != 0) {
        console.log(this.props.num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы постоянно получать уже измененные значения в реакте предусмотрен под это хороший метод `componentDidUpdate`, который вызывается всегда после обновления (правда для первоначального рендеринга он не вызывается). Структура метода такая:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)
```

Этот метод как правило используется для возможности работы с DOM при обновлении компонента. Судя по вашему вопросу - это то, что нужно. Для примера приведу блок кода (согласно документации и вашему вопросу) по этому методу:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // проверим, изменилось ли поле `num`
  if (this.props.num !== prevProps.num) {
    console.log(this.props.num); // вывести в консоль обновленное поле
  }
}
```

Как вы уже заметили, не обязательно использовать все параметры метода, для вашего случая достаточно только первого параметра `prevProps`. Для справки по этому методу добавлю информации о пропсах:

- `prevProps` - это `props` прошлого состояния (то есть старые)
- `this.props` - тут будут новые `props`

Этот метод нужно написать в вашем втором компоненте, там где вы ожидаете значение из `props` и где лежит приведенный блок кода с `componentDidMount`.

Ссылка на источник: [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь у вас отличный ответ

Comment: @MaximSeveryanov рад помочь. Если ответ решил вашу проблему - вы можете выбрать его в качестве верного (принятого) - галочка напротив ответа.